# How to display full html content inside a div or iframe or span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a html content inside a variable like

```
var content='<p>long content.....</p><p>long content......</p><img src="abc.jpg" />'
```

How to display this content fully inside a small div or span or iframe without scroll bar.

I want to show a preview of the content.

Scroll bars are displayed when i use iframe.

Any solution or work around to display the entire content inside a small div or iframe. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS for showing the preview inside a div. For this mention a scale of 50% (or any value suitable for you)

```
transform :scale(0.5); // For Mozilla, Chrome etc
```

For IE you can use ZOOM property.

```
<body style="zoom: 50%">
   CONTENT HERE
</body>
```

Another option is to use **zoomooz.js**

http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: transform helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: now I am able to fit everything inside a div. New problem came now. I am putting a div inside table without apply transform:scale(0.5) and it occupys 692*339 pixel space. Now when I apply transform:scale(0.5) the content of div zooms out but still it occupies 692*339 space. So I am able to see lot of white space around the div.

Comment: Instead of applying the transform to the divs inside, apply transform on the complete table. This will work only if there is no extra content in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a small div is something like a div of the size 500 x 500px. So anyway, it's gonna have a scrollbar as soon as your content is bigger than that size. It is just not possible to display the ***entire*** content without scrollbars. By the way, you should be a bit clearer in your question - in one place you speak of *preview*, then you speak of *entire* content.

Anyway, in order to have a proper fitting preview, you can estimate (or "trial-and-error-style" estimate) how many characters of your content fit in that small preview div. If you have, let's say, 5000 characters, you can just crop your content like:

```
var cropped_content = content.substring(0, 5000);

small_preview_div.innerHtml = cropped_content;
```

Comment: I cannot crop the content as you see their are few images inside the content. I have 4 content variables with html content. Like content1='<p>long content.....</p><p>long content......</p><img src="abc.jpg" />' content2='<p>long content......</p><img src="abc.jpg" /><p>long content.....</p>' I want to show a preview of all these html content. When user selects the one I have to enlarge it. Now i want to show the preview of these html contents inside content variable